# How to compare 2 lists and to get True or False list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Let's assume I have:

```
A = ['a','b','c','d','e']
B = ['a','b','e']
```

I want to compare this 2 lists and get smth like:

```
[True, True, False, False, True]
```

The problem which I have is that lists must have a same length. But how to compare if they aren't?

I need faster way, because I'm working with df with 98800 observations. I searched in internet, but I can not to find what I need.

Thank you

Comment: `[x in B for x in A]` ?

Comment: I didn't get. I know 'in' method, but I'm not sure that I understood your answer.

Comment: what if `B` contained a unique item `'f'`? Can you describe your problem a bit better? Is the comparison based on the values in `A` exclusively?

Comment: You didn't explicitely state what the rule should be to get the output if the lists don't have the same length. Try to explain it, give sample input and output.

Comment: And we could convert `B` to a `set` first to have better lookup time.

Comment: You can check my answer

Comment: @Ev.Kounis sure, my bad. The concept is that 'A' is a list of all possible values(letters in an example). 'B' is a list of random letters. 'B' can not contains any uniques values, only values from 'A'. I want to get True if 'B'[i] in 'A'[i] and False if 'A'[i] not in 'B'.

Comment: @Pon4a, are you using dataframe or list? because they are different types of objects in python.

Comment: I have df(130x98800),but I thought if I save particular column to a list that would be faster. How do you think?

Comment: @Pon4a, you don't have to convert the column to list, you can simply do df['A'].isin(df['B'])

Comment: @Mox Thank you. I will try to work with df. I wrote for loop, but it tooks time for computation (but worked correct). So I will follow your advice!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function from Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
B = ['a','b','e']
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c','d','e']});
df.isin(B)
```

Result

```
    A
0   True
1   True
2   False
3   False
4   True
```

the series version of [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see which elements of list A are in list B, you can do this:

```
result = [x in B for x in A]
```

this is called list comprehension.

This is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for x in A:
    if x in B:
       result.append(True)
    else:
       result.append(False)
```